# How to start my WinJs application snapped to the left?

Tags: javascript, .net, windows-8, winjs

In Windows 8 is there a way to start my WinJs app snapped to the left ?

Or does it always start full screen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to start an application in a snapped view. This is deliberate decision to put the user in control of their Window layout. Let's assume the user has some app already snapped but launching a new app seeminly overrides the snapped app and therefore suspends it. That might have a negative effect on the user's experience.

On the flip side, there is the ability to programmatically attempt an unsnap - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.tryunsnap.aspx.

If there's a compelling reason of why you would want this capability, I know the team is willing to listen.

Comment: I have a timer application that delivers notifications. It would be preferable for this app to open snapped, so as to not completely interfere with the workflow of the user. But I definitely see times where you would have to go straight full screen.

Comment: If nothing else I should be able to start my application on my local machine snapped to the left. It's a pain to have to go threw so many steps just to get to snapped.